# i want to bind two columns from Database into a combobox using vb.net

Tags: combobox, using, vb.net-2010

Can anybody help me.. or teach me how to use an alternative way just to bind it to a combo box. but it should show like a 2 column grid or a table.. not concatenate.

This is my existing code:

```
    strSelectShi = "SELECT ShiftCode, Description FROM tbShift_shift"
    daShi = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectShi, strConPay)   
    daShi.TableMappings.Add("Table", "tbShift_shift")    
    new dsShi = New DataSet    
    dsShi.Clear()   
    daShi.Fill(dsShi, "tbShift_shift")   
    With cbTue
        .DataSource = dsShi.Tables("tbShift_shift")
        .DisplayMember = "Shifcode"
        .ValueMember = "Key"
    End With
    daShi.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display multiple columns in a combobox. What you could do is create a form with the table in a datagridview and open up that form when the user clicks on the combobox.

[Code project file on Flat-MultiColumn Combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MultiColumnFlatCombo.aspx)